# Notation for planes

Tags: geometry, vectors

This might be a dumb question, but I was wondering what symbols/letters are used when labelling planes in 3D. For example, lines are represented using $l$, $m$, $n$, etc... I've seen people using $\pi$ for planes, but are there any others?

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no standard for planes, lines, or points. Only _sometimes_ people use Greek letters for angles,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no standards... most of the time. Different mathematicians use different notations. In any case, people often use $p$, $q$, and $r$.

Comment: If I want to use $\pi$ to represent planes, what letters would I use to label the following planes? I'm assuming they are greek letters.

Comment: I do not know if $\pi$ or greek letters is a good idea to name planes. I would not use them for planes.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for replying.

Comment: You're welcome!